# Error with multiple Access-Control-Allow-Origin hosts

Tags: javascript, http, cors

We have two frontend urls that need to get data from the same API.

The MDN doc says multiple origins are allowed:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

But when I get the following result (in Chrome 68):

*Failed to load http://localhost:8080/api/1.0/test/: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:8080, http://localhost:4000', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:4000' is therefore not allowed access. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.*

### Request headers

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: nb-NO,nb;q=0.9,no;q=0.8,nn;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.5,da;q=0.4,sv;q=0.3
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: (...)
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:4000
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:4000/test
```

### Response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4000
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Cache-Control: private
Cache-Control: max-age=2
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 30 Aug 2018 07:44:51 GMT
```

Comment: So, some information in that MDN article was just plain wrong. Specifically, the Access-Control-Allow-Origin value can’t contain a list of origins. It can only contain either the `*` wildcard or a single explicit origin. Limiting the possible Access-Control-Allow-Origin values to a set of allowed origins requires code on the server side to check the value of the Origin request header, compare that to a list of allowed origins, and then if the Origin is in the list, to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the same value as the Origin value. I’ve updated the MDN article to make all that clear.

Comment: Thank you very much @sideshowbarker, we will whitelist based on the Origin header now.